# Kerberos second-hops using PowerShell Sessions

Tags: powershell, kerberos

I often use PowerShell remote sessions to manage windows servers remotely, generally using the following command, though the following is true for any remote powershell commands such as `Invoke-Command`:

```
Enter-PSSession Server01
```

This works perfectly for almost everything local to that server, but never allows you to reach outside, e.g.:

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession Server01
[Server01]: PS C:\> Get-Item '\\Server02\Share\File'

get-item : Access is denied
```

What is the easiest, secure way to do a second-hop like this? I have a couple answers I'll add, but they generally have caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kerberos constrained delegation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7#resource-based-kerberos-constrained-delegation) to allow Server01 to be able to authenticate you to Server02:

```
Set-ADComputer 'Server02' -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount (Get-ADComputer 'Server01')
```

And some pros/cons from the linked Microsoft doc and myself:

**Pros**

- Credentials are not stored.
- One-liner to set up.
- Stays configured indefinitely.
- One command to cleanup:

  - `Set-ADComputer -Identity 'Server02' -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount $null`
- An AD admin can configure on behalf of someone else.

**Cons**

- Requires Windows Server (and Domain Level) 2012 or later.
- Does not support the second hop for WinRM.
- Requires rights to update objects and Service Principal Names (SPNs) in Active Directory.
- May not take effect immediately due to AD replication times or the KDC cache (see the link).
- Always applies to all users.

To find existing delegations (or ones you've forgotten to remove) run this to return a list:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity -like "*"' -Properties msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity | Select Name,@{l='AllowedFrom';e={$_.'msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity'.Access.IdentityReference.Value}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a credential to a `PSSessionConfiguration` object with the following command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Server01' -ScriptBlock { 
  Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name 'MyUser' -RunAsCredential 'MyDomain\MyUser'
}
```

Then use that configuration to connect and hop:

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server01 -ConfigurationName MyUser
[Server01] PS C:\> Get-Item '\\Server01\Share\File'

# Successful
```

Pros:

- Technically a one-liner to set up
- Can also clean up entirely in one line when you're done:

  - `Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {Unregister-PSSessionConfiguration 'MyUser'}`
- Credentials are encrypted

Cons:

- Credentials are stored on remote computer in reversible format, and [can be stolen](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/96nney/is_it_secure_to_store_credentials_in_a/) by someone with administrator access.
- This configuration stops working when you change the password. (You shouldn't leave credentials lying around anyways)
- Setting a new configuration requires restarting the WinRM service for it to be usable, which ends any existing sessions. (This can be done automatically by adding the `-Force` flag to `Register-PSSessionConfiguration`)

Answer (score 0):

Pass credential object through remote variables:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server02 -Credential $Using:cred -ScriptBlock {hostname}
}
```

Pros:

- Nothing to set up ahead of time.
- Nothing is saved on the remote servers.

Cons:

- `$Using` variables are only available with `Invoke-Command`, and not in PowerShell sessions.
- Requires cmdlets with a `-credentials` flag. `Copy-Item` doesn't have one, but `Start-BitsTransfer` does, so it may take some digging.